# Understanding Machine Check Exception

Tags: linux-kernel

According to my understanding MCE is triggered when the cpu detected some error.
Cosmic particle hitting a register file and altering values should trigger MCE.

Now, I have tried running a linux kernel machine on QEMU and connected a GDB to it, then I altered the ESP register and the machine crashed.

However when I checked the logs, I could not find any traces of MCE.

Why is that?

Comment: Machine Check exception is when CPU detects some hardware faults. Simplest way to observe would be increasing CPU temperature beyond limits, I think .

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question.

Comment: "According to my understanding MCE is triggered when the cpu detected some error. Cosmic particle hitting a register file and altering values should trigger MCE."  :  ---> this will create a SW fault .. not HW fault. So, you are not seeing MCE